# CreatePathNavigator with XDocument in C# (xml with linq)

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a question. Is it possible to navigate to an specific field in an xml and add elements to it?

I tried this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myxmldoc.xml");

doc.Element("Table").Element(Product).CreateNavigator().Add(new XElement("Lamp", "Lamp"));
```

Needless to say it didn't work. The thing is that I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<Table>
    <Product>
        <Chair/>
        <Table/>
        <ChessBoard/>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Chair/>
        <Table/>
        <ChessBoard/>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Chair/>
        <Table/>
        <ChessBoard/>
    </Product>
</Table>
```

As you can see I have many Product tags and I want to be able to add the item Lamp to an specific node with linq. Every time I add elements with:

```
doc.Element("Table").Element("Porduct").Add(new XElement("Lamp", "Lamp"));
```

The Lamp element goes to the first Product node. I want it to go to an specific node, let's say the second one.

Someone advised me to use:

```
doc.Element("Table").Element("Porduct").ElementAt(2).Add(new XElement("Lamp", "Lamp"));
```

But it doesn't work. Visual Studio 2010 says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Elements("Porduct")` (note the **s**) to use `ElementAt()` :

```
  doc.Element("Table").Elements("Porduct").ElementAt(2).Add(...);
```

It would be a little easier if the Products had something to identify them, like an ID attribute.

(And probably you should fix the typo *Porduct* / *Product*)

Comment: Didn't catch my typo. Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow morning and come back with an answer. I have already left work and it's kinda late here.